# using SDL in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sdl

I have downloaded a c++ program. So I decided to run it but it says no such files or directories for SDL.h and SDL_ttf.h files. I installed the libsdl2 package from terminal as well as downloaded it separately. But the problem persists. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and help me with the solution.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should also install the developer tools for `libsdl` and `libsdl-ttf`, which provides the header files, and the binaries which will you link against. I don't know their exact names, but they will end with `-dev`.

Also keep in mind that you have to configure the linker options in Eclipse, to manage to run the program - you just simply add `-lSDL` and `-lSDL_ttf` to the linker options.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
I did it. then I added -lSDL ans -lSDL_ttf in cross g++ linker libraries. still not happening. sorry to ask again

Comment: And is it working now?

Comment: NO. am I doing it right?

Comment: It still says "no such files or directories"? Are the headers included as `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` and `#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>`?

Comment: yes. but it is set like #include "SDL.h". #include <SDL/SDL.h> is also not working

Comment: Could you show me the source? include with qoation marks won't work, that searches in the current directory.

Comment: https://github.com/TheChuckster/EEG_BCI. I am trying to make this device. gl_plot is giving me headache

Comment: Well it should work with <SDL/SDL.h>, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I copied SDL.h ans SDL_ttf.h to the project file and it started working. LOL. thanks alot for helping

Comment: Then it must have been an include error! Somewhere you are still using quotation marks instead of looking up the path